# C++ singleton template class crashes my program

Tags: c++, inheritance, singleton

I created a singleton pattern as a template class.

```
template <typename T>
class TemplateSingleton
{
protected:
    TemplateSingleton() { }
    virtual ~TemplateSingleton() { }

public:
    static T * GetInstance()
    {
        if (m_pInstance == NULL) 
            m_pInstance = new T;

        return m_pInstance;
    };

    static void FreeInstance()
    {
        if (m_pInstance != NULL)
        {
            delete m_pInstance;
            m_pInstance = NULL;
        }
    };

private:
    static T * m_pInstance;
};

template <typename T> T * TemplateSingleton<T>::m_pInstance = NULL;
```

And use inherited from child class.
This class can be used as a singleton by inheriting a template, or as a generic class if not inherited.

```
#define MAX_COUNT 8

class CDataHandler : public TemplateSingleton<CDataHandler>
{
public:
    CDataHandler();
    ~CDataHandler();
    ...

private:
    CDataObj m_clDataObj[MAX_COUNT]; // CDataObj *m_clDataObj ?
    DWORD m_dwDataObjCount;
    ...
};
```

```
class CDataObj
{
public:
    CDataObj();
    ~CDataObj();
    ...

private:
    ...
};
```

The code above is in a DLL, and the program is implemented to call only the instance constructor of CDataHandler.
And my program crashes and quits.

By the way, if I change CDataObj member variable from array to pointer, it works fine.
(In this case, new in the constructor of the CDataHandler, and delete in the destructor.)

Is there something wrong with this code?

Addition) 
constructor and destructor code for CDataHandler :)

```
CDataHandler::CDataHandler()
    : m_dwDataObjCount(0)
    //, m_clDataObj(NULL)
{
    // Do nothing

    // m_clDataObj = new CDataObj[MAX_COUNT]; 
}
```

```
CDataHandler::~CDataHandler()
{
    //if (m_clDataObj != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COUNT; i++)
        {
            m_clDataObj[i].Close();
        }

        // delete[] m_clDataObj; 
        // m_clDataObj = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: How have you implemented CDataHandler ctor and dtors?

Comment: The cause of your crash is in the code you decided not to show us.

Comment: @Arun Added constructor and destructor source code for CDataHandler

Comment: @SidS Are there any grammatical errors in the code above? If so, the problem should be considered somewhere else....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is causing your program to crash, but there are two potential problems in the code you posted.

First, you don't know when `m_pInstance` will be initialised to `NULL`. If you call `GetInstance()` during static data initialisation, `m_pInstance` might not yet be initialised to `NULL` and thus `GetInstance()` will return some invalid pointer. Look up "static data initialisation order fiasko" or something like this, there is a lot of information on this.

To avoid this, you can use local static variables, along the lines of:

```
T* GetInstance()
{
  static T* t = new T{};
  return t;
}
```

Second, you use a template for your singleton. That's okay, but you have to take care: If the definition of the class is available to more than one compilation unit, each of these compilation units will instantiate their own singleton, leaving you with multiple different instances depending on from which compilation unit you are accessing them.

To solve this, you can use `extern template` for a certain `T` in the DLL to tell others they should not instantiate this template specialisation and then compile an explicit template instantiation into the DLL to provide the implementation for everyone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
After several days of debugging, it seems to be something other than a template singleton.
I have found that the logs related to Fault Tolerant Heap (FTH) are written to DebugView, and it works when I initialize the FTH list.